# Why I get segfault in a dummy C program which is compiled to MIPS32 (R3000) with -nostdlib?

Tags: c, mips

I am trying to write a C program that calls a function, and result of this function is returned as an exit code. Here is my attempt:

```c
int increment(int a) {
    return a + 1;
}

void __start() {
    // Call the increment function and get the return value
    int exitcode = increment(1337);

    // Perform the exit system call
    asm volatile (
        "li $v0, 0x1096\n"    // exit system call number (0x1096 for MIPS)
        "move $a0, %0\n"  // exit code
        "syscall\n"       // invoke the system call
        :
        : "r" (exitcode)
    );

    // This line should never be reached
    while (1) {}
}
```

It is compiled like this:

```c
/usr/bin/mips-linux-gnu-gcc -static -mno-mt -mfp32 -march=R3000 -EB -O0 -DNDEBUG -nostdlib main.c -o program
```

I run it with `qemu-mips` like this:

```bash
$ qemu-mips -d in_asm,cpu program
----------------
IN: __start
0x0040015c:  lui        gp,0x2
0x00400160:  addiu      gp,gp,-32716
0x00400164:  addu       gp,gp,t9
0x00400168:  addiu      sp,sp,-32
0x0040016c:  sw ra,28(sp)
0x00400170:  sw gp,16(sp)
0x00400174:  li a0,1337
0x00400178:  lw t9,-32744(gp)
0x0040017c:  nop
0x00400180:  bal        0x400150
0x00400184:  nop

pc=0x0040015c HI=0x00000000 LO=0x00000000 ds 00a2 00000000 0
GPR00: r0 00000000 at 00000000 v0 00000000 v1 00000000
GPR04: a0 00000000 a1 00000000 a2 00000000 a3 00000000
GPR08: t0 00000000 t1 00000000 t2 00000000 t3 00000000
GPR12: t4 00000000 t5 00000000 t6 00000000 t7 00000000
GPR16: s0 00000000 s1 00000000 s2 00000000 s3 00000000
GPR20: s4 00000000 s5 00000000 s6 00000000 s7 00000000
GPR24: t8 00000000 t9 00000000 k0 00000000 k1 00000000
GPR28: gp 00000000 sp 407fff50 s8 00000000 ra 00000000
CP0 Status  0x20000010 Cause   0x00000000 EPC    0x00000000
    Config0 0x80008482 Config1 0x9e190c8f LLAddr 0x0000000000000000
    Config2 0x80000000 Config3 0x00000000
    Config4 0x00000000 Config5 0x00000000
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

See that it shows segfault in the end?

If I compile same program with -O3, function `increment` is optimized away, return value is precalculated - and program works successfully. With experiments I found that any function call adds a segfault to the program... Why?

Comment: Where is the stack pointer initialized?

Comment: @MartinJames You mean, that my program inside __start should initialize correct sp, correct? How do I know the correct value? Should I setup auxv by myself?

Comment: Dunno, it's your system, your memory map:)  Not sure that's your problem, but segfault on call with valid arguments/parameters and correct calling convention, especially with _start entry and no crt?  Imma betting on invalid SP:)

Comment: Ummm.. 'C run time', not 'critical race theory'.

Comment: @MartinJames do you have any literature about implementing custom CRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, because I found proper solution.

1. VM (QEMU or Unicorn) should set `SP=` address where `argc` is stored. Stack grows from lower addresses to higher addresses (grows up).
2. Create a file `crt.s`, compile it with `mips-linux-gnu-gcc`, include it in your build.
3. Now you can add `main`, define and call any functions, that will work.

```
# https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/mips/start.S.html
# stack layout:
# sp: argc
# sp+4: argv
# sp+((argc+1)*4): envp

.text
.globl __start
__start:
    .set push
    .set noreorder
    move $ra, $zero     # reset $ra
    lw $a0, 0($sp)      # load argc
    addiu $a1, $sp, 4   # $a1 = $sp + 4

    # calculate $a2 = $sp + ((argc+1)*4)
    addiu $t0, $a0, 1   # $t0 = argc + 1
    sll $t0, $t0, 2     # $t0 = t0 * 4
    addu $a2, $sp, $t0  # $a2 = $sp + $t0

    # advance stack pointer 1 page down
    addiu $sp, $sp, 0x1000

    jal main             # call main
    nop                  # delay slot

    move $a0, $v0        # save return value
    li $v0, 4001         # exit syscall
    syscall              # do exit
    .set pop
```